# Coloring Row in QTableView instead of Cell

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pyqt5

**Backstory:** Using an imported UI, I place my table onto a QTableView. I also make use of alternating row colors to better differentiate rows.

**Problem:** I'm looking to color the ***row*** of a table that contains a `True` value in one of the columns. I am able to color the ***cell***, but have not found a way to color the entire row. I use a PandasModel class to format the tables:

```
class PandasModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
def __init__(self, data, parent=None):
    QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent)
    self._data = data

def rowCount(self, parent=None):
    return len(self._data.values)

def columnCount(self, parent=None):
    return self._data.columns.size

def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
    if index.isValid():
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return str(self._data.values[index.row()][index.column()])
        if role == QtCore.Qt.BackgroundRole:
            row = index.row()
            col = index.column()
            if self._data.iloc[row,col] == True:
                return QtGui.QColor('yellow')
    return None

def headerData(self, col, orientation, role):
    if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal and role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
        return self._data.columns[col]
    return None
```

I've look through numerous examples, and I am aware there may be multiple ways to color a table using QBrush or QColor, but so far the best I am able to do is simply color the cell that contains the `True` value. Splicing in code from other examples, I thought it was possible that the `col = index.column()` was getting in the way, as maybe it was limiting it to the cell, however, when I remove this it becomes ambiguous.

**Important:** I am wanting to keep the alternating row colors that I set elsewhere in the script, so please keep that in mind! I am only looking to color the specifics rows that contain any `True` value.

Comment: So, the row should have a specific background if ***any*** of the columns of that row has a `True` value? Note that the `if self._data.iloc[row,col] == False: pass` is completely useless: remove it and you'll get the exactly same result.

Comment: Right, the other columns associated with the table will never hold a True/False value, so essentially it can only refer to a single column. I'll remove `if self._data.iloc[row,col] == False: pass`  portion from my code, and my original question.

Comment: And is that boolean column known when the model is created?

Comment: Yes, the model is created after the df is created. With that thought, I tried replacing `col = index.column()` with `col = DF['column']` with no avail (received this: NotImplementedError: iLocation based boolean indexing on an integer type is not available). That may be due to how I am formatting the column, if you'd like I can add that to the question, if you think that may be the cause.

Comment: To clarify, when printing `DF['column']`, it returns a column of False/True values, randomly assorted, so it appears as a boolean column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the column of the boolean values is known, you just have to check for the value of that column at the given row of the index.
Supposing that the column index is 2:

```
class PandasModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, data, parent=None):
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent)
        self._data = data
        self.boolColumn = 2

    # ...
    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if index.isValid():
            if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
                return str(self._data.values[index.row()][index.column()])
            if role == QtCore.Qt.BackgroundRole:
                row = index.row()
                if self._data.iloc[row, self.boolColumn] == True:
                    return QtGui.QColor('yellow')
```

<sup>Note: `return None` is implicit at the end of a function block, you don't need to specify it.</sup>

Comment: Epic, yeah setting the column specific to the boolean column totally works. Thanks! Your intuition is good, the column index is 2.